# What is this element in Android Studio?

Tags: android

[image: Sample image]

What is this? Where can I find this element, how is it called?

This seems not to be a seekbar. I tried to find it.

Comment: Some people choose to create their own views, and not use standard components. There is no default view included in android like this.

Comment: You can use and customize seekbar or number picker or spinner similar in that picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's called `RangeBar` with special effects you can found a tutorial [here](http://androidarena.co.in/tag/range-bar/)